# Batch file input with arguments

Tags: batch-file, input

I'm working on a batch LAN chat which has a supported list of commands. I wanted all commands to have arguments rather than taking the user to separate input prompts.

For example:

> `Set /p m=[Command]`

So if the user enters:

> send hi

It would make variables:

- `m=send`
- `arg=hi`

This should work with any text like "say" or "ban" not just "send".

How can I go about implementing this using Windows 7. I can post the entire code if needed.

Comment: Add details about language and platform, there are many libraries available on github.com to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on your question which is converting a command:

> send hi

To variables:

- `m=send`
- `arg=hi`

You can do this with a `FOR` statement.

```
REM Get user command.
Set /p m=[Command]

REM Reset arg variable.
SET "arg="

REM Parse command and arg out of the user entered value.
REM Tokens are broken up by a space.
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%A IN ("%m%") DO (
    SET m=%%A
    REM arg variable will get all text after the first space.
    SET arg=%%B
)

ECHO Command = %m%
ECHO Arg = %arg%
```

So entering:

> send hello world

Will output:

```
Command = send
Arg = hello world
```

Comment: @MythTheWolf - Essentially you would just play with the `tokens` part of the `FOR` loop. For example, changing to `tokens=1,2,*` would mean that inside the loop, `%%A` is the text before the first space, `%%B` is the text between the first and second space, and `%%C` would be everything after the second space. You would just need to adjust your logic accordingly to use these values.